# How to identify location of intermittent water leak?

Tags: plumbing, water

In the master-bath I have an over-sized tub and separate glass shower stall that are right next to each other, both on-top of sub-flooring / a crawl space.  (Crawl space is because house is built into the side of a hill, not flat ground).

The insulation in the crawl space under the shower and bath was a little wet when I pulled it off.  Additionally, I've had termite damage to the plywood underneath the shower stall and basically no where else, indicating their attraction to moisture.

When I run both the bathtub and the shower -- turn on both hot and cold faucets on each -- and go back underneath the crawl space, I see no leakage, even with it running for a while.  The pipes are dry, with no water dripping or build up, etc.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you flood tested the bath and shower with dye?

Comment: Was the plywood water stained? Does the shower have silicone caulk in the corner joints and the floor joints? Are any grout joints in the shower cracked or missing? Try getting someone to spray the shower at various locations that look suspect while you observe for leaking from below.

Comment: Ah thanks, good ideas.   Can't tell about the wood too well cause termites ate it!  About a 2 foot square section under the shower.   But the insulation is wet between the 2x8's supporting the plywood, so perhaps it's dripping down directly from the shower.  While the shower has tile, the bottom of it does appear to be metal.  I think I will caulk the whole thing real well.

Comment: Could be coming in from outside?